# How to make WordPress use new Upload Path settings in Multisite Setup

Tags: multisite, uploads, options

I have a site that is setup for WordPress multisite.

The main site works, but the subdomains are not functioning as I would like them to.

#### Here are the settings for the main site:

- Upload Path: `media/images/national`
- Upload URL Path: `http:// images.mydomain.com/national`
- Fileupload Url: `http:// www.mydomain.com/media/images/national`

These settings work, and I am able to upload images to the specified folder. However, when I try to use similar settings for any of the subdomains, WordPress ignores my settings and use its default settings, which are:

- Upload Path: `wp-content/blogs.dir/4/files`
- Upload URL Path: `(blank)`
- Fileupload URL: `http:// cityname.mydomain.com/files`

I want all of my media files to go to my media folder and not the `wp-content/blogs.dir folder`.

How can I get WordPress to use the settings I place in `Upload Path`, `Upload Url Path` and `File upload Url` instead of it defaulting to it's own settings?

Final note: this also happens on a fresh install.

Comment: shouldn't [wp_upload_dir()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) take care of this for you?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/network-shared-media/ This plugin appears to take care of all of that!

Answer (score 5):

In a multisite setup, you need to adjust the upload_path for each individual site through the Network Admin menu.

Go to /wp-admin/network/sites.php. Edit the site in question. On the settings tab, you can find the Upload Path setting and change it to whatever you want.

You can also adjust the URLs on this page. Look for "upload".

Note that this doesn't apply retroactively. Only new uploads will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress multisite's "Upload Path" should be set to a server-relative path (e.g. `/home/serveraccountname/public_html/wp-content/uploads`).

The "Upload URL Path" should be the URI (e.g. `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads`).

Ignore the `/sites/1/` fragment for sub-sites - WordPress will add these automatically.

Comment: This helped, thank you!

Comment: What if I want /sites/1/ to be sites/something-specific-to-the-individual-site? Like, I may need to add more sites, but I'd like to be able to see easily which uploads folder applies to which site. The number isn't very descriptive.