# Make uploads live outside of the WP folder

Tags: multisite, uploads

I'm working on a template that basically sets up WP in the following manner:

- /
- /wp
- /content/plugins
- /content/themes
- /media

Using the /media folder to store and serve uploads on single-site installs is easy enough:

```
add_filter('pre_option_upload_path',      function($val) { return '../media'; });
add_filter('pre_option_upload_url_path',  function($val) { return '/media'; });
```

It seems a bit less trivial to change for multi-site installs. A cursory look in the WP code yields functions like `ms_upload_constants()` and all sorts of checks related to `is_multisite()` whenever uploads occur, and cursory googling yields little to nothing.

Is there a documented procedure to make a WP multisite do a similar trick with `/media/$site_id` in the above setup? Or is it primarily a matter of tricking WP into writing into the correct location by using symb links (or something to that order)?

Comment: Not able to test this now, but I'd take a look at the filter `pre_site_option_$option`. Are you going to store all MS uploads in a single folder?

Comment: @brasofilo: I'd like to store them like `/media/$site_id`. So not related to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77132/using-same-directory-for-storing-all-uploaded-images-on-a-wordpress-network but possibly related to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/how-to-make-wordpress-use-new-upload-path-settings-in-multisite-setup